# Is there any chance to call phtml file into system.xml file?

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, system.xml, system-config

Hello,

I have to know that any chance to call phtml file into system.xml if yes then how is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to call phtml file in system.xml?

Comment: because of login in custom extension.

Comment: Can you elaborate your situation in more detail?

Comment: I have to call one phtml file login and logout and call fieldss

Answer (score 0):

In system.xml, add frontend model

> mymodule/adminhtml_system_config_testbtn
>                               87
>                               1
>                               0
>                               1

In your block, you can modify the html output, and you can add yr logic & load other required data here.

```
<?php 

class Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Testbtn extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{

     /**
     * Generate button html
     *
     * @return string
     */
     public function getButtonHtml()
     {
         $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                ->setData(array(
                'id'        => 'my_button',
                'label'     => $this->helper('adminhtml')->__('Send Product (Test)'),
                'onclick'   => 'javascript:check(); return false;'
            ));

        return $button->toHtml();
    }
    /**
     * Return element html
     *
     * @param  Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
```